# Preprocessor directives are not getting collapsed when I fold a function with non-indented pragmas in VSCode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, preprocessor-directive, code-folding

I'm making a unity game and trying to fold a function, but my preprocessor directives (checks if it's on android or not) are not getting collapsed. Only code until the directive is collapsed.

Code before folding:

[image: code before folding]

Code after folding:

[image: code after folding]

Indenting the pragma directive until its indentation is the same as code within that block works, but I want to use the proper format, plus it looks easier to see.

I found [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/407) but sadly it was only for the C++ tools extension, and I am using C#. Is it possible to collapse this without indenting it?

Comment: I don't have this problem, disable all the extensions with `code.exe --disable-extensions` to see if this problem is caused by an extension.

Comment: @shingo I tried it, it still does the same thing.